# WPF Template shortcut to image source

Tags: c#, wpf

I have all of my images stored in a single folder in my wpf project, is there a way to reference the source path without having to copy and paste it all over the project?

Currently I have the following working

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
    <Setter TargetName="BtnImage" Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Project;component/Images/BlueGear.png"/>
    <Setter TargetName="RefreshGrid" Property="Background" Value="#FAFAFAFA" />
    <Setter TargetName="BtnText" Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
</Trigger>
```

I would eventually like to just reference the image path of

```
pack://application:,,,/Project;component/Images/
```

to something like

```
Source=Images/BlueGear.png
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Why not put the image in a style: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/773386/WPF-ImageButton. Then use the style everywhere you need it

Comment: If `Project` is not a different assembly than that of your XAML, you can simply omit the `pack://application:,,,/Project;component/` prefix and just write `Value="Images/BlueGear.png"`. However, this works only in XAML, but not in code behind.

Answer (score -1):

Try change `Build Action` in `Properties` of your image in solution to `Resource`.